# AVSpeechSynthesizer does not work on iPad

Tags: ipad, avspeechsynthesizer

This simple code works fine on my iPhone, but not on my Pad. The speech synthesizer remains silent on the iPad, no matter what. What could be the problem? Speak from selected text does work on the iPad, no errors. no warnings, no messages, nothing.

I use Xcode 6, iPhone 5s and iPad 4, both on iOS7.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer; 

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)Speak:(id)sender 
{  NSString* Phrase = @"Hello world!"; 
   synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init]; // init speech synth }
   AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:Phrase];   
   [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I have the same identical problem... did you get any hint?

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that in my case it was the side switch that was configured as a mute switch. That's what happens when your kids know the passcode of your iPad.

Answer (score 0):

It was a 8.0 bug.
@(#)8.1 fixed the problem.